# Bind Enumeration to path or query in play

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a scala `Enumeration` as follows:

```scala
object SearchTypes extends Enumeration {
  type TypeAlias = Value
  val firstVal, secondVal, thirdVal = Value
}
```

I want to be able to pass it in through a query string - my `routes` looks like

```
/search  @searchController.search(searchType: SearchTypes.TypeAlias)
```

When trying to run the play application, it throws a series of errors including this:

> [error] /Users/my-user/code/project/conf/routes:8: No QueryString binder found for type SearchTypes.TypeAlias. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.

How do I teach play to parse the `Enumeration`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good in-depth write-up [here](http://www.ethanjoachimeldridge.info/tech-blog/easy-custom-class-enum-route-binding-in-play), but the crux is to implement `QueryStringBindable.Parsing` **inside your `Enumeration`**. Example:

```scala
object SearchTypes extends Enumeration {
  // other declarations

  implicit object searchTypeQueryStringBinder 
    extends QueryStringBindable.Parsing[SearchTypes.TypeAlias](
      withName(_), 
      _.toString, 
     (k: String, e: Exception) => "Cannot parse %s as SearchTypes: %s".format(k, e.getMessage())
  )
}
```

(You can write more sophisticated case-based parsing logic by replacing the direct call to `withName(_)` with something more complicated.)

After doing this, the `routes` should be satisfied because `play` can convert between a `string` and your `Enumeration`.

Note that if you want to use your `Enumeration` in the path directly - rather than in a query string - you'll need to extend `PathBindable.Parsing` rather than `QueryStringBindable.Parsing`.